# multiplatform mobile application development

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, gluon-mobile, kmm

Is there anybody who kindly help me to make a decision between kotlin multi-platform mobile (KMM) with android studio versus javafx (gluon) for IOS/Android application development.

-Run time performance (startup time, code size,power consumption, etc)
-Learning curve of KMM ( I do not know Kotlin but I learn it if development environment of KMM  is just on windows for two target platforms. [android development in gluon requires linux / windows wsl2 and there is no clear step by stem instruction to install the development env. I feel that assuming every gluon candidate user is expert on linux/wsl is wrong]

I am experienced system/software architect who gets retired in a year :). I like to continue with mobile+backend in my remained days.

Thanks a lot in advance.

a.lgl

Comment: Actually it is not opinion based since i have put  three (3) metrics into the question. Metrics are more or less measurable.But anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting but also very opinionated question. I've tried both and for the near future I will stick with JavaFX. There are a few issues which you should be aware of.

1. JavaFX covers the main desktops, mobile platforms and with JPro even the web with just one code base. You can program it in any VM language (Java, Kotlin, ...)
2. KMM basically only covers the non GUI parts and it is expected that you provide a native implementation of the GUI for each platform. You are bound to Kotlin and I found it difficult to find replacements for all the Java libraries which I used for platforms other than the VM (iOS, web, ...)

Comment: Thank you very much for very fast response.